# PHP Variable Not Being Executed In Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, datetime

I have a DateTime that I created as two variables for this month and last month using format('m') to get the the number for the month. I am then putting this into a mysql query but the query doesn't work when using the variables but does if I put the numbers in manually. I can call the variable and it echoes the two correct dates so I'm a bit at a loss to why it's not working in the mysql query.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

```
    $lastmonth = new DateTime();                                        
    $lastmonth->modify('-1 month');
    $lastmonth = $lastmonth->format('m');
    $thismonth = new DateTime();
    $thismonth = $thismonth->format('m');
    $thedate = "BETWEEN '2015-$lastmonth-16' AND '2015-$thismonth-15'";
    $query = ("SELECT unid FROM responses WHERE (date $thedate)");

    $stmt =  $db->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
```

I have also tried:

```
    $lastmonth = new DateTime();                                        
    $lastmonth->modify('-1 month');
    $lastmonth = $lastmonth->format('m');
    $thismonth = new DateTime();
    $thismonth = $thismonth->format('m');
    $query = ("SELECT unid FROM responses WHERE (date BETWEEN '2015-$lastmonth-16' AND '2015-$thismonth-15')");

    $stmt =  $db->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use like:

```
    $lastmonth = new DateTime();                                        
    $lastmonth->modify('-1 month');
    $lastmonth = $lastmonth->format('m');
    $thismonth = new DateTime();
    $thismonth = $thismonth->format('m');
    $thedate = "BETWEEN '2015-".$lastmonth."-16' AND '2015-$thismonth-15'";
    $query = ("SELECT unid FROM responses WHERE (date ".$thedate.")");

    $stmt =  $db->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: and then print the query

Comment: Sorted thanks, I had done that originally but forgot to put it around the $thedate variable in mysql. :)

Comment: Ok so my answer is helpful?

Comment: Yet another copy-and-paste solution source without proper explanation.